# Create excel form webservice

Tags: php, sql, excel, web-services, open-source

I am looking for an OpenSource project or a simplistic means to build my own service. I have several standardized Excel 2010 forms that individuals fill out. Once completed, the forms are emailed and archived and then later all the data from all the forms are combined into a single report. Works great.

This is for remote users to be able to submit forms to me (like travel request/expense/etc). Right now they just email me.

I would like to, instead, have all the forms submitted to a service on my server that takes the needed data fields and stores in a database. Then would like to be able to create reports from that data. I imagine I would need to build a management console that pulls the submitted reports individually for an approval process and the ability to modify previously submitted forms. All my forms are uniquely identified via a random number generator already by the way.

Has anyone seen such a service in the opensource world and if no, what would be the best route to create such a thing. I am not even sure of what google keywords I need. So far I have been trying 'excel database service' and such.

Comment: I don't even know why you'd need a web service. Can this not be done with a windows forms application that just sticks everything into a centralized SQL server installation?

Comment: This is for remote users to be able to submit forms to me (like travel request/expense/etc). Right now they just email me. Id like to automate the process as much as possible. And pull reports remotely.

Comment: From the background of a database and BI developer, I would add "ETL" to your search terms when trying to find a solution. To make sure I understand, you want users to submit excel files to a folder somewhere, iterate through the files, and store them in a new excel file?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is with a simple web form then, that hooks up to SQL server. That way it's accessible remotely and you can manage the data very easily.

Comment: The advantage of a web form over excel files is that with a web form, you have control over the incoming data.  If you are programatically reading excel files, you are hoping they have the data you expect in the spots where you expect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest answer I can give you is, Google Microsoft.Interop.Excel

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Its the Microsoft library that you will need to use to handle the excel files.

From a high level, you will need to :

1. When the client uploads the file; via a website, your web service or method will receive a bit stream which you need to write to a temporary excel file on your web server, using Interop.
2. Open the temporary file using Interop, then: 
     for each row 
          read specific sheet[row][cell] that you want into variables, or class, and then insert the values into your db.
     end for each
3. Close the file, store it in a back up folder or delete it, etc.